# Jaxb unmarshal custom xml hard

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following XML:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <id>......<id>
        <author>....<author>
        <set01_start>.......</set01_end>
        <set01_summary>.....</set01_summary>
        <set01_end>.........<set01_end>
        <set02_start>.......</set02_end>
        <set02_summary>.....</set02_summary>
        <set02_end>.........<set02_end>
        <set03_start>.......</set03_end>
        <set03_summary>.....</set03_summary>
        <set03_end>.........<set03_end>
    </book>
    <book>
        <id>......<id>
        <author>....<author>
        <set01_start>.......</set01_end>
        <set01_summary>.....</set01_summary>
        <set01_end>.........<set01_end>
        <set02_start>.......</set02_end>
        <set02_summary>.....</set02_summary>
        <set02_end>.........<set02_end>
    </book>
</books>
```

I'm trying to map it to the java class.
But I have a problem with the list set.
I tried to use `@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` annotation for this case
but all data in sets was null

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
public List<Object> set;
```

And Set Claas

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Set {
@XmlElement
private String start;
@XmlElement
private String end;
@XmlElement
private String summary;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to write conventer for changing xml structure. 
In this form i can easy parse it.

```
<books>
<book>
    <id>......<id>
    <author>....<author>
    <set>
      <start>.......</_start>
      <summary>.....</summary>
      <end>.........<end>
    </set>
    <set>
      <start>.......</end>
      <summary>.....</summary>
      <end>.........<end>
    </set>
    <set>
     <start>.......</end>
     <summary>.....</summary>
     <end>.........<end>
   </set>
</book>
<book>
    <id>......<id>
    <author>....<author>
    <set>
      <start>.......</end>
      <summary>.....</summary>
      <end>.........<end>
    </set>
    <set>
      <start>.......</end>
      <summary>.....</summary>
      <end>.........<end>
    </set>
</book>
```

But after maping to object i need to save new objects in old form xml.

Maybe someone has a better idea?